# Brightness Control doesn't work anymore after ubuntu installation

Tags: drivers, nvidia, xorg, brightness

Os:Ubuntu 22.10, NVIDIA Driver 390

After the ubuntu installation the brightness slider and hotkeys stopped working, when I press the hokey button on my lenovo w520 with an i7 and a nvidia quadro 1000m the slider appears but seems to do nothing. When I used the live stick to try ubuntu It worked fine, but right after installation it stopped working completely. I'm super confused now and already tried some fixes but nothing seemed to work. I hope someone has an idea how to fix it.

Update: This command works to change the brightness but I can#t find away to map this to my brightness hotkeys:

```
xrandr --output LVDS-0 --brightness 1
```

Comment: Ok I somehow fixed it by disabling the proprietary nvidia driver and switching to wayland.